# IPCamera Feed is not working in Android Pie

Tags: ip-camera, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to show feed from IP Camera to android Application. I have code working for all devices except android Pie. Can't figure out the problem, below attached is the logcat, android code for camera feed and Manifest file.

[Files](https://filebin.net/9z4kmwfprluyzfec)

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with Camera2 api?